# What Python exception should I throw when an external hardware connect fails?

Tags: python, exception, hardware

I am writing some Python code that uses a library to communicate with an external piece of hardware over USB.  When the hardware library is unable to connect to the device, it returns False - otherwise it returns True.

I would like to examine this return and use it to trigger an exception - to be more Pythonic.  What would be the most appropriate exception type to throw?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

An `IOError`.  From the [docs](http://docs.python.org/library/exceptions.html#exceptions.IOError):

> Raised when an I/O operation (such as a print statement, the built-in
>   open() function or a method of a file object) fails for an I/O-related
>   reason, e.g., “file not found” or “disk full”.

You may want to wrap this in your own exception like:

```
 class ExternalDeviceNotFound(IOError): pass
```

and raise that instead.  This gives the calling code more options on how to handle the error.